# rstudio, smth with plot.design

Tags: r, plot

Colleagues, good afternoon!
Very much in need of your help! I work with the value of acidity in the soil depending on the depth of sampling and soil damage. I need to build a plot.design with a custom scale, but all attempts fail.
Here is the code and the picture I get as a result. But I wanted to add y-values that are less than 5.5 and greater than 6.0 to it. Can you tell me how to do this?

```
  Damage   Lay KCL.pH
1 Damaged 0-10 5.66
2 Damaged 10-20 5.15
3 NotDamaged 0-10 5.03
4 NotDamaged 10-20 5.79
5 Damaged 0-10 6.37
6 Damaged 10-20 6.09
7 NotDamaged 0-10 5.55
8 NotDamaged 10-20 5.51
9 Damaged 0-10 6.86
10 Damaged 10-20 6.15
11 NotDamaged 0-10 5.58
12 NotDamaged 10-20 5.60
```

```
setwd("C:/Users/User/Desktop")
Data <- read.table(file = "1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
Data$Damage = factor(Data$Damage,
levels=unique(Data$Damage))

Data$Lay = factor(Data$Lay,
levels=unique(Data$Lay))
plot.design(Data)
```

Result, but I need to see more numbers on y

[image]

Please, HELP! :-)

Comment: `plot.design(Data, ylim=c(4,8))`?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: r2evans, thank you more, you've been very helpful! I tried to use this command before, but for some reason I always got an inapplicability error because of the equality of x and y